# barplot2 error on Confidence intervals?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

So, I have this table

```
              Ccela      Cviri      Dfrag      Pfict
     S.obs    1759.00000  634.00000  747.00000 1714.00000
     S.chao1  2610.80685 1374.29167 1192.63830 2192.72862
     se.chao1   83.85972  122.35336   63.93822   55.99704
```

Which I would like to see plotted by **barplot2**, or any other, with the confidence intervals corresponding to the `se.chao1` row and both `S.obs` and `S.chao1` plotted as a group for each column.

For this, I have tried to use `barplot2()`, for which I have extracted the last row into two files (for `ci.u` and `ci.l`) and deleted it from the previous table. This way, I got 3 tables with the same dimensions, after adding an empty row to both `ci.l` and `ci.u`.

Running the following:

`barplot2(new_barplot, legend = row.names(barplot_est.plot), beside=TRUE, plot.ci = TRUE, ci.l = ci.l[1,], ci.u = ci.u[1,], col=c("lightblue","lightcyan"))`

I got the following error

> Error in barplot2.default(new_barplot, legend =
>   row.names(barplot_est.plot),  :    ‘height’ and ‘ci.u’ must have the
>   same dimensions.

Is there another way of doing this with **barplot2**?

If not, can you show me a way of doing this with **ggplots2**, for example?

Thank you in advance!

André

Comment: `ggplot2` lets you do this from the data directly: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_errorbar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the link suggested by Max Ghenis, this could be one way to go. I rearranged your data first. Then, I created `limits` which you need when you draw error bars.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(t(mydf)) %>%
add_rownames() %>%
gather(group, value, - c(rowname, se.chao1)) -> mydf2

limits <- aes(ymax = value + se.chao1, ymin = value - se.chao1)

g <- ggplot(data = mydf2, aes(x = rowname, y = value, fill = group)) +
     geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
     geom_errorbar(limits, position = dodge, width = 0.25) +
     labs(x = "Assign your name", y = "Value")

ggsave(g, file = "april12.png")
```

[image]

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(Ccela = c(1759, 2610.80685, 83.85972), Cviri = c(634, 
1374.29167, 122.35336), Dfrag = c(747, 1192.6383, 63.93822), 
Pfict = c(1714, 2192.72862, 55.99704)), .Names = c("Ccela", 
"Cviri", "Dfrag", "Pfict"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("S.obs", 
"S.chao1", "se.chao1"))
```

EDIT

Seeing the OP's comment I did the following. In this version, you see error bars only for `S.chao1`.

```
mutate(mydf2, se.chao1 = replace(se.chao1, which(group == "S.obs"), NA)) -> mydf3

dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.9)

ggplot(data = mydf2, aes(x = rowname, y = value, fill = group)) +
geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
geom_errorbar(data = mydf3, aes(ymax = value + se.chao1, ymin = value - se.chao1),
              position = dodge, width = 0.25) +
labs(x = "Assign your name", y = "Value")
```

[image]

Comment: Hello again! This worked perfectly, but how can I plot the error bars only on the S.chao1 bars? And how can I take out that space between zero and the names?

Comment: @AndréSoares I think you want to rearrange `limits`. When you write a code there, you probably need to subset your data. As for the space, you may be able to remove the space by using `scale_y_continuous()` and set up a value range.

Comment: any ideas on how to rearrange limits? The only way I see to delete those is to export ir as a .svg and take them out by hand... :)

Comment: what if based on a similar table now with a standard error for obs, lets say 'se.obs', I wanted to plot se.obs as a SE for S.obs and se.chao1 as a SE for S.chao1?